# In Eclipse setting classes as list view forces close

Tags: android, eclipse

After following code and showing no errors when I use my button to access my list view it forces close my code is as follows

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Listview extends ListActivity {

String classNames[] = {"home1", "Sweet", "tutorial2"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,   android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classNames));

}@Override
protected void onListItemClick (ListView lv, View v, int position, long id){
    super.onListItemClick(lv, v, position, id);
    String openClass = classNames[position];
    try{
        Class selected = Class.forName("us.beats.with." + openClass);
        Intent selectedIntent = new Intent(this, selected);
        startActivity(selectedIntent);
    }catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: nothing shows in the error log but log cat reads as follows

Comment: 12-30 07:07:41.277: E/AndroidRuntime(14128):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)                                     12-30 07:07:41.277: E/AndroidRuntime(14128):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)      and theres alot more i will comment my activity in my manifest next

Comment: <activity
            android:name="Listview"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="us.beats.with.Listview" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: But still nothing shows in the error log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

where the button was set up I had  Button Listview = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Listview);
        Listview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        startActivity(new Intent("us.beats.with.Mylist"));
        mpButtonClick.start();
```

but start activity was us.beats.with.Listview should have been the above

Answer (score -1):

Change your classname and run it will work fine

Comment: sorry to sound like a moron but im self teaching and very new to programming are you refering to my Listveiw.java or selected from Class selected = Class.forName If your refering to Listview how do i do that in eclipse

Comment: so i did change my Listview.java to Mylist.java and same thing happened no change

Answer (score -1):

```
    public class MyList extends ListActivity {

String classNames[] = {"home1", "Sweet", "tutorial2"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,   android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classNames));

}@Override
protected void onListItemClick (ListView lv, View v, int position, long id){
    super.onListItemClick(lv, v, position, id);
    String openClass = classNames[position];
    try{
        Class selected = Class.forName("us.beats.with." + openClass);
        Intent selectedIntent = new Intent(this, selected);
        startActivity(selectedIntent);
    }catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

> Now run the above code

Comment: ok Like i said it is the same code i wrote just with different class name and I have no errors I run it and when i use the button It forces close still I copied your code as well and it still forces close